# UITexfled keeps focus after I click done button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm new to xCode and Objective C. I'm working on a simple calculator app just to learn...
I've gotten as far as I can, googled and searched to find answers but am stuck on a few things...

I have a textfield that gets a value when someone clicks on a UIPickerView. This works fine  but when I click my done button, using the code below, it keeps focus.
I have played around with EndFirstRepsonder and EndEditing but neither removed the flashing cursor...

As a side note the animation only works once on show and doesn't work to hide...

```
//Show Picker Wheel
- (IBAction)showPickerWheel:(id)sender 
 {

  //This line hides the default keyboard
  [sender resignFirstResponder];

  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
  CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 20);
  _pickerViewContainer.transform = transfrom;
  _pickerViewContainer.alpha = 1;
  [UIView commitAnimations];

 }


//Hide Picker Wheel
- (IBAction)hidePickerWheel:(id)sender 
 {

  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
  CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 20);
  _pickerViewContainer.transform = transfrom;
  _pickerViewContainer.alpha = 0;
  [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resignFirstResponder in the didEndEditing delegate method like this:

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Please bear with me. I don't understand. I tried adding this a couple of ways but it doesn't change anything. Can you please explain?

Comment: Hi Patrick sure, so In your ViewController (which I presume is where the above code you posted is) add the code that I have in my answer. It's a special method called a delegate that will get called automatically by the system (iOS) when the done button is touched on the keyboard. If you also put an NSLog statement in the method you will see it being called. You must remember to set the delegate of your textField to your viewController. You can do this is code like this: myTextField.delegate = self;

Comment: Ok I have the UITextField delegated to my view controller by ctrl click and dragging the blue line to the view controller. It shows "delegate" if I look in the connections inspector. I have the code from above in this view controller .m file. I added this NSLog(@"%d", YES); but nothing is showing in the log. I'm sure this is something simple but I am so new I'm just not catching it...